# Regex for matching string with double backlash or backlash followed by double quotes

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex that satisfies the following condition:

- Can contain any character that is not `\n` and `\r`. Can be empty string.
- Can contain `\"` and `\\`, but `"` and `\` are not allowed.

Positive examples: `abc d`, `my \"time\"`, `D:\\willy\\wonka`, `foo\\\"bar`.

Negative examples: `my "laser"`, `D:\willi\badehose`, `foo\\"bar`.

I tried using positive lookbehind, but `abc d` is not matched and `foo\\"bar` is matched:

```
^[^\r\n]*(?<=\\)("|\\)[^\r\n]*$
```

How can I fix this? Here is the link to regex101 for ease of testing: https://regex101.com/r/I1byls/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a pattern to exclude matching newlines, `\` or `"` and only match `\"` or `\\`

As all the quantifiers are optional, you could also match an empty string.

```
^[^\r\n"\\]*(?:\\["\\][^\r\n"\\]*)*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\r\n"\\]*` Optionally match any char except the listed in the character class
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `\\["\\]` Match either `\"` or `\\`
  - `[^\r\n"\\]*` Optionally match any char except the listed in the character class
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9TxMY/1)